# Getting filename of an XML file with XQuery

Tags: java, xquery, exist-db

I store my entities in the eXist XML database and I use a file name (resource id) as an ID of an entity.

Example:

```
String xquery = "for $movie in collection('/db/movie')//movie "
    + "return $movie";
```

After executing this query I retrieve `org.xmldb.api.base.Resource` instance whose content I use to create an entity. When I want to set an id of this entity, I do it like this:

```
dvd.setId(rs.getId());
```

The problem is that if I execute query like this:

```
String xquery = "for $dvd in collection('/db/dvd')//dvd "
        + "return <dvd>"
        + "{$dvd/title}"
        + "{$dvd/type}"
        + "{"
        + "<content>"
        + " {"
        + " for $movie in $dvd/content//movie"
            + "     let $movieIn := doc(concat(\"/db/movie/\", $movie/@id))/movie"
        + "     return "
            + "                    <movie id=\"{$movie/@id}\">"
            + "                          {$movieIn/name}"
            + "                          {$movieIn/director}"
            + "                          {$movieIn/year}"
            + "                          {$movieIn/country}"
            + "                          {$movieIn/actors}"
            + "                          {$movieIn/genres}"
            + "                    </movie>"
        + " }"
        + "</content>"
        + "}"
        + "</dvd>";
```

`rs.getId()` returns `null`. I also tried method `getDocumentId()` from [this class](http://xmldb-org.sourceforge.net/xapi/api/org/xmldb/api/modules/XMLResource.html), but it returns `null` as well. Is there a way of making it return the id of the resource (which is the name of the file which the entity is stored in) ?

If it's not possible, is there a way (function or something) of getting the file name of the file which I'm working with (I mean, the database retrieves data from) with an XQuery query ?

I tried replacing this line:

```
+ "return <dvd>"
```

with this:

```
+ "return <dvd id=\"{$dvd}\">"
```

(so that I could get the name of the file from the attribute) but it doesn't return the file name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be looking for `fn:base-uri()`. See [here](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_base-uri.html).

Comment: Thanks ! Great. But if there is something that returns only the name of the file (not whole uri), let me know please.

Comment: You could probably do something like `fn:substring-after(fn:base-uri($dvd),fn:static-base-uri())`. Or another replace with `fn:replace()`. I dont know of a function that does it directly.

Comment: I use fn:substring(fn:base-uri($dvd), 9) (because I know that the uri has always the same length) but thanks for the idea!

Comment: I'd suggest to use `document-uri( root( $dvd ) )` instead, it returns (as documented on that page) the same, but it prevents potentially issues with base attributes when present...

Answer (score 13):

Since you're using eXist-db, you can use the [util:document-name()](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#document-name.1) function:

```
util:document-name($dvd)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fn:base-uri` will return the whole URI rather than the last part of the URI, but you can use a regex solution combined with the `fn:base-uri` function for a solution that is not dependent on eXist-specific functions.

This particular regex trims the extension with **\.\w+$** and captures the filename without extension in capture group 2

```
declare namespace db="http://basex.org/modules/db";
declare namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";
declare variable $path as xs:string external;

let $docs := collection($path)
for $doc in $docs
return
let $file := replace(fn:base-uri($doc),'^(.*/)(.*?)\.\w+$','$2')
return db:replace('13F', $file, $doc)
```

Alternatively for the whole filename with extension

```
  let $file := replace(fn:base-uri($doc),'^(.*/)(.*?\.\w+$)','$2')
```

Comment: Yeah the first answer doesn't actually give a method to get only the file name, rather the whole file path or uri. It's really not answering the question.  [http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_base-uri.html]  And the second is exist-db specific. This ones works with basexdb. I read this in the comments "But if there is something that returns only the name of the file (not whole uri), let me know please" I thought that's what was being asked and wasn't.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the important parts of your comment into it because it is *very useful* for people who are just scanning answers. I saw the OP accepted the `fn:base-uri` answer and thought it did everything the OP wanted. I see now that the comments indicate otherwise. As you can see, people skip comments.

Comment: `return let $file := ` is invalid syntax in eXist 2.2, and your regular expressions won't work for files that have no extension (which is quite possible).

Comment: Thanks Louis, yeah I didn't put the full code there. I had just just put some partial code to show the regex mostly. The code there now works in basex. It saves a collection of xml documents in basex named by the filename without the extension. I haven't tested in on existdb but db:replace is a basex function I believe so would need adjusting on existdb.